# React Router v6 404 / Wildcard Route with Basename

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navigation, react-router-dom

I'm trying to implement an app router using React Router v6 that has a basename `/foo`:

```
export const appRouter = createBrowserRouter(
     createRoutesFromElements(
         <Route element={<Layout />}>
             <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
             <Route path="/requestAccess" element={<RequestAccess />} />
             <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
                 <Route path="/createEvent" element={<CreateEvent />} />
                 <Route index element={<Dashboard />} exact />
                 <Route path="/admin-console" element={<UserAdminDashboard />} exact />
                 <Route path="/view-previous" element={<ViewPastEvent />} exact />
             </Route>
         </Route>
     ),
     {
         basename: "/foo",
     }
);
```

I would like to catch 404s with a <Route path="*" element={}/> so that a path like localhost:5000/bar would redirect to localhost:5000/foo, but all my routes exist as children of /foo so I'm not sure how to implement a 404 that catches both localhost:5000/foo/this-route-is-a-404 as well as localhost:3000/bar/bar-is-not-the-basename-of-this-app.

I have tried adding `<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/foo"/>}/>` as a sibling of `<Route element={<Layout />}>` but createRoutesFromElements() expects only one root element.

Any help is appreciated. I could not find anything in the React Router docs that helps with this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to catch 404s with a `<Route path="*" element={}/>` so
> that a path like `"localhost:5000/bar"` would redirect to
> `"localhost:5000/foo"`, but all my routes exist as children of
> `"/foo"`

When the app is hosted from a `"/foo"` directory then the app and router is running relative to this path. The server will need to redirect page requests from `"/"` to `"/foo"` to "bootstrap" it into your app. How you handle this depends on your server environment or hosting service.

When you are running localhost you'll typically just navigate manually after starting the app since the app is running from root `"/"`.

> I have tried adding `<Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/foo" />} />` as a sibling of `<Route element={<Layout />}>` but
> `createRoutesFromElements()` expects only one root element.

You can render sibling routes in a `React.Fragment` component.

```
export const appRouter = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route element={<Layout />}>
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route path="/requestAccess" element={<RequestAccess />} />
        <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
          <Route index element={<Dashboard />} /> // <-- "/"
          <Route path="createEvent" element={<CreateEvent />} />
          <Route path="admin-console" element={<UserAdminDashboard />} />
          <Route path="view-previous" element={<ViewPastEvent />} />
        </Route>
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} /> // <-- redirect to "/" home path
    </>
  ),
  { basename: "/foo" }
);
```

But since the redirect to the `"/"` doesn't present anything visually, there's no reason to render it outside the `Layout` layout route. Rendering the redirect within the layout route should work equally well.

```
export const appRouter = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route element={<Layout />}>
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      <Route path="/requestAccess" element={<RequestAccess />} />
      <Route element={<PrivateRoutes />}>
        <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
        <Route path="createEvent" element={<CreateEvent />} />
        <Route path="admin-console" element={<UserAdminDashboard />} />
        <Route path="view-previous" element={<ViewPastEvent />} />
      </Route>
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
    </Route>
  ),
  { basename: "/foo" }
);
```